# How to generate a mongodb _id from document payload unique value, while insert?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

I have some documents to insert into a collection, and I'd like to set the _id for each document.

Let's assume my original document is like

```
   items = [
     { 
       somedata: {
        //unknown
       }, 
       someUniqueId:"a not standard hex long string e.g. 69Al0MOMXEC8ZPhSf6JJ8w" 
     }
   ]
```

I am doing then something like this before invoking insertMany

```
        const toInsert = items.map((el) => {
        const hashedHexElId = md5(
          el.someUniqueId
        ).substring(0, 24); // <--- I dont like this but it's needed since it wont accept >24 chars


        const _id = new ObjectId(hashedHexElId);

        return {
          ...el,
          ...{ _id }, // Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
        };
         await db.insertMany(toInsert);
```

Any best practice  to obtain this?

Note that I'm doing this since I'd like to sync data from another remote resource into my Collection in a way drop-insert (wipe and insert back all)

But also I'd like to relate mongodb collection id to the document's internal primaryKey, which is not a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer

Comment: `_id` is generated automatically, what's wrong with it?

Comment: As mentioned in the end. If I do bulk inserts from another resource, how can I grant not having duplicated documents? If not reusing internal PK form the other system?

Comment: Still not clear what you mean, but you can simply use `ObjectId()` to generate the id.